# Setting up a delay notification with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need to write a php function for sending a Telegram notification after 4 hours.

With the application i'm posting data into a SQL db, after I pressed the Submit button, i need that a php function starts and after 2 days sends to my Telegram channel a notification, with some of the data that i've posted into the db record.

For the posting part and Telegram part i'm ok, i've already linked the website to the channel and normal notifications from php work fine, but i need some advice on the "reminder" part.

I was thinking about some date() function and post the value in to the record, make another var with the date + 2days e make some for or while cycle but i don't think that this can works. Some advice? 
I'm new to php, maybe i dont know some function that could help me?

Comment: Your approach is right. Create a column with the date/time to remember/define when to send the remember and configure a cronjob (Linux) or task scheduler (Windows) to perform an automatic execution. Also, you could use the PHP to schedule a cron/task.

Comment: add 48 hours in ur news when inserting in table and display all the notification that has current time. your current time will be news which u added 48 hours before. that will give you notification almost 48 hours old or so on. i dont see much detail so i posted my idea.

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't nothing about cron job, but this is not a problem i can search the official guide, but just a question. After the remind is setted, it works every 2 days cyclic and i need another function to stop it or i can set it to remind me just one time and die? Sorry for the english :)

Comment: Thank you Deepak, i don't have a lot of details to because for the moment I'm just structuring it and I needed to understand in which direction to go before I started writing it

Comment: I'll write a better answer, just answer me, is your remember notification a mail?

Answer (score 0):

- Add to your table a column and name it **notification_send** and give it a default value of **0**
- Create a [crontab](https://crontab.guru/) that calls a php file for example:

  - ***/60 * * * * php -f /etc/www/my_notification.php** : calls the file every 60 mintues
- In this file create a query that selects all the data with the **notification_send** = **0** then check if the **current_date** - **date** column of each row => 2 days :

  - If so : update the **notification_send** value to **1** and send your notification

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, your approach is right. As you asked something more, though, I chose to write an answer.

As you asked, when you send a Telegram notification you have to send a reminder notification after 2 days (48h). If I'm right it's an e-mail.

First of all, as you said, you have to create a column to warn when the remember should be send.

Also, to know if the reminder has been sent or not you have to create another column. It could be a flag (`true`/`false`) or a `datetime` column (`null` = not sent, `filled` = sent).

Besides that, a cronjob or schedule have to call a PHP script. I'll show to you an example of a PHP script.

I'll call the table as `reminder` and the column `sendIn` and `isSent`.

```
//select only the reminder that has the sendIn lesser than now and that not has been sent
$statement = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM reminder WHERE sendIn <= NOW() AND isSent is null");

//prepared statement to update the reminder sent
$updateStatement = $pdo->query("UPDATE reminder SET isSent = NOW() WHERE id = :id");
foreach($statement as $reminder)
{
    /**
      script to send the reminder

    **/

    //update the reminder
    $updateStatement->execute(array(':id' , $reminder['id']));
}
```

To create a cronjob, you could take a look here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

You don't need to delete the cron, just let it run periodically and send all your reminders.

Comment: Thank you very much, the reminder it's not a mail but a simple file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$channel."&text=".$text); because i send the message with a bot that ruin the channel. I start working on it, I appreciated your help